# SQL - Using COUNT with alias shorthand

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and having trouble performing a query that uses `COUNT`.

I have a movies database with three tables:

Table `public.movies`:

```
    Column    |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
--------------+---------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------
 id           | integer |           | not null | nextval('movies_id_seq'::regclass)
 title        | text    |           | not null |
 release_year | integer |           | not null |
 runtime      | integer |           | not null |
 rating       | text    |           | not null |
 studio_id    | integer |           |          |
```

Table `public.stars`:

```
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
------------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id         | integer |           | not null | nextval('stars_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name | text    |           | not null |
 last_name  | text    |           |          |
 birth_date | date    |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "stars_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "roles" CONSTRAINT "roles_star_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (star_id) REFERENCES stars(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Table `public.roles`:

```
  Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |              Default
----------+---------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 id       | integer |           | not null | nextval('roles_id_seq'::regclass)
 movie_id | integer |           |          |
 star_id  | integer |           |          |
Indexes:
    "roles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "roles_movie_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "roles_star_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (star_id) REFERENCES stars(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I'm trying to select the first and last names of every star along with the number of movies they have been in, and group everything by first and last name (as to not have any duplicate stars). This is what I tried:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, m.COUNT(*)
FROM movies m
JOIN roles r
ON m.id = r.movie_id
JOIN stars s
ON r.star_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.first_name, s.last_name;
```

I keep getting `ERROR: schema "m" does not exist`.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax just uses `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, COUNT(*)
FROM movies m JOIN
     roles r
     ON m.id = r.movie_id JOIN
     stars s
     ON r.star_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name;
```

To avoid duplicates, use the primary key in the `GROUP BY`.

Note that you don't need `movies` in the query:

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, COUNT(*)
FROM roles r JOIN
     stars s
     ON r.star_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name;
```

Finally, if a star can play more than one role in a movie, you will want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT r.movie_id)` in the `SELECT`.